# Django - passing data with 'include'

Tags: python, django

I'm a newbie in Django and here's what I want to do: I want to have a base.html that includes a Navigation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'nav.html' %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

pretty simple, but: The navigation should render it's own content flexible, as i want to add a cms later.

```
  <nav class="nav">
    {% for item in sites %}
      <a class="nav__item" href="{{ item.href.value }}">{{ item.label }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </nav>
```

I have a render method of index.html (which just extends base.html and adds an h1 tag for testing purposes) like so

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    opts = {
      'sites': [
        {
          'href': {
            'value': '/someurl'
          },
          'label': 'Some Label'
        },
        {
          'href': {
            'value': '/lorem'
          },
          'label': 'Lorem Ipsum'
        },
        {
          'href': {
            'value': '/contact'
          },
          'label': 'Contakt'
        }
      ]
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', opts)
```

but if I run my local server my content does not get passed.

Comment: is there any error showing up?

Comment: no error. it renders the h1 properly. in the Inspector i see that my nav tag is showing up. but with no content

Comment: add `<pre>sites : {{ sites }}</pre>` in your base template and check what you really get. If it's what you expect, then add the same snippet in `nav.html`.

Comment: Also: are you sure you are using `jinja` as the template engine ? I know jinja owes a lot to Django but you code looks like standard django template language.

Comment: unfortunately it's empty.

Comment: i thought django standard django template language is the same as jinja. I must have mixed that up. so it's django standard

Comment: I presume when you say h1 you mean href?  If you past the content of the include into the main template, does it work ok?

Comment: This may be a stupid question but, this is your only view that render this content? Could it be that you are using a different view?

Comment: it is my only function and my only view

Comment: I can reproduce your code (copy/paste) and it works ok. It may be where is `nav.html` placed?

Answer (score -1):

You should use `{% include "nav.html" %}` inside the `{% block content %}` tag.
Otherwise it won't be shown.

Comment: That would be true if the include was in a child template, but here it's in the base template.